# What's the convention when it comes to functions with a lot of optional parameters?

Tags: c#, conventions, optional-parameters

I have a simple HttpsGet function that takes ~20 optional parameters.

Right now I'm thinking between making every parameter optional and having the user create a custom Options object that they will use with the function. Creating 200 overloads is out of the question.

What would be the best way about making the function readable and easy to use for other users? Am I missing another solution?

Here's a simplified version of the code for the sake of readability.

```cs
static List<Assignments> GetAllAssignments([Optional] string levels, [Optional] string passed, [Optional] stringresurrected)
{               
    var json = Get($"assignments?{levels}&{passed}&{resurrected}");
    var assignments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionResponse<Assignments>>(json).Data;
    return assignments;            
}
```

Comment: you can pass object with nullable properties as your parameter?

Comment: I'd be concerned about a method with 20 optional parameters, whether it's invoked internally or via HTTP. If one call can pass 10 parameters and another can pass 10 different parameters, it's hard to image how they're both doing the same thing. That method would likely be complicated and difficult for developers to look at. Perhaps one way to simplify is to consider the scenarios in which callers might include different parameters and create more specific methods for those scenarios.

Comment: "_I have a simple HttpsGet function that takes ~20 optional parameters._" A function with twenty optional parameters is anything but simple... ;-)

Comment: @ScottHannen I already made separate methods for such scenarios, the ~20 I mentioned are the leftovers. If a user would love to look at assignments which are not hidden, not passed, which exist somewhere in the range between levels 7 and 16, and were updated after 4th of July it's not for me to decide whether they should do it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually best to have a "Options Object" that you pass this in instead of the individual values. Otherwise it can be quite easy for callers to pass the wrong value.

```
static List<LevelProgression> GetLevelProgressions(LevelProgressionOptions options) 
{ 
}
```

Where the options might look like this

```
public class LevelProgressionOptions
{
    public LevelProgressionOptions()
    {
        // Set any default values
        SomeProperty = 1;
    }

   public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
   public string AnotherOption { get; set; }
   //  other values omitted
}
```